# Use of "constellation" to mean "situation"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, colloquial-language

I was reading this question on the Personal Finance and Money site: [How close is the fate of Berkshire Hathaway tied to Warren Buffett?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/124291)

> Will Berkshire Hathaway remain a good investment in the long term? Are there other examples in history with a similar **constellation** where conclusions can be drawn from?

Notice how "constellation" is used. In this context, it appears to mean "situation". This is the first time I have seen "constellation" used in this way. Is this common colloquial usage, or is it archaic?

Comment: Their profile says they're in Germany. They've probably used "constellation" because "Konstellation" would be a very typical word to use there in German.

Comment: (Note too that the grammar of the sentence, is plain **wrong** .. "where conclusions can be drawn from" is just completely wrong.  My guess is the entire sentence was translated by google.)

Comment: The word constellation is sometimes used to mean a recognizable pattern or arrangement of things. In medicine, for example, a constellation of symptoms means a recognizable set of symptoms which indicate a diagnosis. The Eurion constellation is a specific pattern of rings printed on money intended to make counterfeiting by copying more difficult.

Comment: @ChrisH, what are the connotations of the German word "Konstellation"? You might want to include it in an answer if it's significantly different from the existing answers.

Comment: @Jetpack it’s more or less exactly what the top-voted answer here suggests: a particular combination or configuration of circumstances. (It also has the same “arrangement of stars” meaning as the English word, but the more general usage is much more common in German than it is for English *constellation*)

Comment: If I'd have known that the use of one single word would entail such a long discussion, I'd surely had chosen a different word for this.

Comment: @ChrisH That's exactly what made me use this word.

Comment: @Fattie describing the sentence as "completely, totally, utterly wrong" strikes me as serious overstatement for a perfectly clear (if not quite idiomatic) sentence. It's also just plain rude.

Comment: hi @ChrisH - I definitely didn't mean to be rude! - my bad.  (Thanks, I deleted the comments in spite of the immediate many upvotes.) It's pretty normal to discuss language vigorously.  The sentence is completely wrong (in at least three ways); it's little more than a typo or machine translation. And the word use in question is simply and totally: wrong.  The answer to the literal question in the QA headline title is simply "No".

Answer (score 15):

It doesn't quite mean situation. It's a less common use of the word constellation that applies figuratively to events or qualities.

[Here's a dictionary entry that shows this:](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/constellation)

> 3. a group or configuration of ideas, feelings, characteristics, objects, etc., that are related in some way:a constellation of qualities that made her particularly suited to the job.

We often make explicit what were talking about, for instance saying **constellation of events** or **constellation of qualities** instead of using the word  "constellation" alone as was done in the answer you linked to. You could consider there to be a bit of ellipsis in that example.

Comment: Perhaps the author was thinking along these lines: constellation = arrangement of stars = arrangement of events = situation.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean a situation. It means a collection/configuration of situations or a collection/configuration of factors. It has the same meaning as when used for stars

Comment: @Flux - the word is simply ***wrong***.  Any normal English editor would have just replaced it with a correct word.  (Say, "situation.")  The author (or likely, google translator) wasn't "thinking" of anything.  It's just completely, totally wrong.

Comment: The sentence given by the OP is completely, totally, **utterly wrong** (in a number of ways).  It reads exactly like a humorous "google translation".   It is very confusing to supply an answer which says anything other than "Oh that's a typo or a mistranslation."

Comment: @Fattie it's impossible to know for certain what was in the mind of the writer, but constellation can be and is used figuratively to mean items arranged in a pattern. That's a real English usage. I agree the sentence is wrong, but the word itself is not necessarily wrong.

Comment: B, of course (obviously) there are correct uses of "constellation".  The sentence given by the OP is just plain incorrect.

Comment: @Fattie noting the possibility for the OP's text having been messed up by machine translation etc., but if we back-translate "constellation" to "configuration"- i.e. the particular combination of people and corporate structure- it makes much more sense. It would make even more sense if the original term were something like "aspect" which in astrology means something along the lines of "layout", hence could very easily be (mis-)translated as the astronomical term "constellation". And don't you dare accuse me of not knowing the difference between astrology and astronomy...

Comment: @Fattie Isn't it possible to draw conclusions from sonething? Like every good automated  translator, I am always ready to improve my knowledge and my capabilities. (But the assumption that I didn't think anything hurts me a bit.)

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the following definition:

> ***constellation***
>
> a group of associated or similar people or things.

“Constellation” in your context is really referring to a group/set of circumstances, and they are associated in that they are all factors contributing to some outcome (in this case, the eventual benefit from a long-term investment).

In this way, I think your assessment of it meaning “situation” would be quite accurate (but it’s important to understand why, i.e. only use “constellation” where there are multiple factors or “points” that make up the “situation”).

Answer (score 1):

## Both Part and Whole

I think the other answers have the gist of the meaning, but I would like to refine the word a bit.

A constellation is not *just* "a collection of stars".  It includes the idea of some recognizable outline or figure.  A bunch of cows standing in a field forms a collection of cows, but if someone said: "Look at that constellation of cows!" I would assume that the cows were standing in a unique pattern that evokes some image.  Otherwise, it is just a random herd of cows, not a "constellation" by any stretch of the imagination.

A sample of stock picks over 50 years is just a group of stock picks.  It is only reasonable to call them "a constellation" if there is some pattern which emerges from the picks, such as: "produced a large market-beating return".  One could abstractly call the resulting "shape" "a winner".

To this extent, the usage of the term in the original post is indeed a bit peculiar, and not well-chosen, IMO.  It seems to refer to Warren Buffet, or Berkshire Hathaway, neither of which can be easily imagined as "a collection" of anything, unless one wishes to imply that BH is itself "a collection of long-term investments".  But then, to ask whether there are other examples from which we can learn implies that "the shape" of BH is, in some sense, recognizable in some other financial corporation.  This could very abstractly refer to the value investing strategy that Buffet & friends are known for, but it would be strange to say that a value-oriented portfolio constitutes "a constellation".

A better example, I think, is to consider star athletes.  In basketball, professional-level players are rarely good at more than two positions.  They usually have a few favored stats for which they contribute an outsized performance for the team, whether points, rebounds, assists, steals, etc.  I think a good use of "constellation" might be something like: "Consider Magic Johnson.  As a big man, he was an unusual point guard.  His size allowed him to play as forward or center as the situation allowed, making him an extraordinarily flexible player.  Are there any players today with his constellation of skills and talents?"

This speaks to the answer which observes the "constellation " form which most commonly occurs.  But note that NBA fans can likely imagine an abstract outline of "Magic Johnson's skills" as a kind of literal constellation in the mind's eye.  To that extent, every player could be considered to have "a constellation of talents", and that would not even be an inappropriate usage of the idiom.  But perhaps it is used more for remarkable instances, where the collection forms something more meaningful, even *iconic* than mundane instances.  For instance, if one were to name a random 3rd string NBA player, and asked even a hardcore fan to describe his "constellation of abilities", they would likely struggle to describe anything coherent or noteworthy.

On the other hand, someone with more knowledge of the NBA than I could probably name one or two players in the mold of Magic Johnson that do indeed "evoke his constellation of talent", which shows that the metaphorical "figure" produced from his particular set of abilities is indeed recognizable as a whole, and not just a collection of parts.

Answer (score 1):

The literal meaning of "constellation" refers not merely to a collection of stars, but a collection of stars for which some greater meaning is seen. For instance, the Orion constellation is said to look like a hunter. None of the stars individually look like a hunter, but together they do. The stars combine to form something with a property none of them individually do.

My understanding of the figurative use of "constellation" is a collection of factors that work together to produce some effect that none of them individually produce. The term "perfect storm" has similar meaning, but usually refers to bad things, while "constellation" can be good or bad.

Answer (score 1):

With "constellation" I meant to refer to the relation investment company - one "big boss" at its top - boss likely to die in the next years -> fate of company unknown.

I didn't think about stars at all when I used this wording; as others already said, with constellation (Konstellation) I had in mind "how things are arranged".

Comment: But *constellation* is not used like that in English.

Answer (score -2):

It isn't common usage. Unlike the other answers, I believe the linked quote is simply the result of the author using the wrong word.

A "constellation" is literally a collection of stars. From that we get the figurative meaning of a collection of data points forming a pattern. This does not fit the sentence though because there is not a collection of data points.

Thinking laterally, I believe the author probably meant "star quality". This would explain them misusing the word "constellation", and it also fits with the nature of Berkshire Hathaway which the question relates to.